# ScalaTest: Checking that list does not contain element

Tags: scala, scalatest

so i am new to scala and i need to check that a List does not contain an element.

here is the code i'm trying to write but abviously my syntax is wrong and i don't know how to do it:

```
  it should "return unique slugs for all category" in {
    val allCategories = categoryService.getAllCategories("rocket")
    val checkedCategories = List()
    allCategories.foreach(
      category => checkedCategories should notContains category.slug
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  checkedCategories should not contain category.slug
```

You can use `not contain` for **collection** contains checking.

http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could just map the slugs first and then check the sequence against its distinct self

```
val slugs = categoryService.getAllCategories("rocket").map(_.slug)
slugs.distinct.size shouldBe slugs.size
```